# Hamiltonian and Thermal Energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, hamiltonian

I was reviewing my lessons when I read this definition on Thermal Energy:

> The sum of potential energy and kinetic energy is equal to Thermal Energy

But isn't this the same as the Hamiltonian? So, instead of saying "taking the Hamiltonian of ..." can I say "taking the Thermal Energy of ..."? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: More on [Hamiltonian vs. total energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamiltonian+energy).

Comment: I don't agree with the definition. The sum of potential energy and kinetic energy at the atomic/molecular level equals the total internal energy. The term "thermal energy" is sometimes used to refer to kinetic energy part of internal energy because temperature is a measure of average molecular kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you integrate the Gibbs equation $dU=TdS+ \sum_k Y_kdX_k$ with the assumption of $X_k$ and $U$ are extensive and $Y_k$ are intensive, then the function $U(S,X_k)$ are first order homogeneous and there follows that $U=TS+\sum_kY_kX_k$. This can be interpreted as the total *internal* energy of a body containing two terms $TS$ and $\sum_kY_kX_k$. The former $TS$ is the internal *thermal* energy, the latter is the internal everything else reflecting the various interactions the system may participate in, such as mechanical $X_1=V, Y_1=-p$, electrical $X_2=q_e, Y_2=\phi_e$, chemical, magnetic, etc. This has nothing to do with the Hamiltonian for $U$ is a *static* (timeless) energy while the Hamiltonian is a dynamic quantity so much so that even if $H$ is explicitly time independent it describes the time evolution of other dynamic quantities.

Comment: I don’t know what intensive and extensive is so I will go with your word :)

Comment: *Extensive* is "stuff" such as mass, electric charge, number of molecules, electric or magnetic polarization, volume, surface area,  and energy, etc. *Intensive* is gravitational potential, chemical potential, pressure, surface tension, electric field intensity (voltage difference), etc.